# Modify the command text of an sql query based on certain cells

Tags: sql, excel, vba

In an excel file, I have a table which is retrieving data from an external source using a sql query. I am wondering how to, using VBA, refresh this table by modifying the highlighted element based on the text found in a specific cell in the same excel file.

[image]

I was thinking of just using vba to "rewrite" the command text but I do not know how to make the highlighted element a variable based on that other cell.

```
    Sheets("B1 query").Select
    Range("F5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query from Blueone32").ODBCConnection
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT DISTINCT cre.cre_id" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & ", cre.cre_HR_ID" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & ", cre.CRE_ALPHA" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & ", cre.CRE_LAST_NAME" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & ", cre.CRE_FIRST_NAME" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & ", pos.PT_L" _
        , _
        "ABEL" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "-- , CASE " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "--   WHEN PT_LABEL LIKE '%CPT%' THEN 'CPT'" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "--   WHEN PT_LABEL LIKE '%FO%' THEN 'FO'" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "-- ELSE PT_LABE" _
        , _
        "L" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "--  END FUNCTIE" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & ", gco.gco_type" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & ", tev.lps_label" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & ", gco.gco_start" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "--, gco.gco_end" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "-- , gco.gco_end-gco.gco_star" _
        , _
        "t" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & ", to_char(gco.gco_start,'RRRR')" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "-- , to_char(gco.gco_start,'HH24:MI:SS')" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "-- , to_char(gco.gco_end,'DD-MON-RRRR" _
        , _
        "')" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "-- , to_char(gco.gco_end,'HH24:MI:SS')" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "-- , gco.gco_end-gco.gco_start" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM master.v_assignments asg" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & ", master" _
        , _
        ".v_crews cre" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & ", MASTER.V_POSITIONS pos" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & ", master.v_training_events tev" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & ", master.v_ground_courses gco" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE cre.CR" _
        , _
        "E_ID = asg.ASG_CRE_ID (+)" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "AND asg.ASG_POS_ID = pos.POS_ID" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "and asg.asg_id = tev_asg_id" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "and gco.gco_id = asg.asg_g" _
        , _
        "co_id " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "AND (CRE.CRE_ALPHA like '2%' OR (LENGTH(CRE.CRE_ALPHA) = 3))" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "AND cre.CRE_ACTIF='Y'" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "AND gco.gco_end<to_dat" _
        , _
        "e('10MAY2023 23:59:00','DDMONYYYY HH24:MI:SS')" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "AND gco.gco_start>to_date('30oct2022 00:00:00','DDMONYYYY HH24:MI:S" _
        , _
        "S')" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "AND asg.ASG_D_TYPE = 'GCO'" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "AND tev.lps_label IN ('W-AVSEC')" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "ORDER BY gco.gco_start, cre.CRE_ALPHA" _
        )
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .Connection = Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DRIVER=CONNECTION_STRING" _
        ), Array( _
        "LUEONE;DBA=W;APA=T;EXC=F;XSM=Default;FEN=T;QTO=T;FRC=10;FDL=10;LOB=T;RST=T;BTD=F;BNF=F;BAM=IfAllSuccessful;NUM=NLS;DPM=F;MTS=T;" _
        ), Array("MDI=Me;CSR=F;FWC=F;FBS=60000;TLO=O;MLD=0;ODA=F;STE=F;TSZ=8192;"))
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .SavePassword = True
        .SourceConnectionFile = ""
        .SourceDataFile = ""
        .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
        .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
    End With
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query from Blueone32")
        .Name = "Query from Blueone32"
        .Description = ""
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query from Blueone32").Refresh
    With Selection.ListObject.QueryTable
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = True
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Before `.CommandType = xlCmdSql` add line `.CommandText = Replace(.CommandText, "W-AVSEC", Sheets("SheetName").Range("??").Value2`) where ?? is the cell reference you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a paramterised query. Instead of `AND tev.lps_label IN ('W-AVSEC')` use

```
AND tev.lps_label IN (?)
```

(Although why use "IN" for a single value, = would be more efficient). Then use an ODBC Paramter to pass the value you want e.g. (warning, untested code)

```
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
 With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandText = sql
    .CommandType = adCmdText
End With
Dim parm() As ADODB.Parameter
ReDim parm(0) As ADODB.Parameter

Set parm(0) = .CreateParameter("lpsName", adVarChar, adParamInput)
parm(0).Value = ws.Range(x).Value 'whatever your range is
parm(0).Size = 255     'NB Size in mandatory for adVarChar parameter types
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To UBound(parm) - 1
   cmd.Parameters.Append parm(i)
Next
```

Also - all those `Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10)` can be replaced with `VbCrLf` - not that there is any need for them at all - the code does not need to look pretty, it's not a human reading it

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Although the response of @CDP1802 is working, I'd really like to try out your solution but I could be lacking the knowledge to fully understand. I have tried integrating your code to the VBA code initially pasted, but I get a user-defined type note defined straight off the bat.

Comment: My bad - I used ADODB in my example, you are using ODBCConnection - it also has Command and Paramter types though so substitute in the correct types. My code is only an example, as I stated.
See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0